# setState in function not working | Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I'm doing this `_optionSelected` function (Line 63) but it won't work. I tried changing many things, but every time I get into the widget page, it just keeps the index 0 and the color white in my text. It doesn't follow the `setState()` function. Image here:

[image]

The code is here:

```
import 'package:robotics_community_app/utils/card_image_list.dart';

class Components extends StatefulWidget {
  const Components({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _ComponentsState createState() => _ComponentsState();
}

class _ComponentsState extends State<Components> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return PageView(
      physics: BouncingScrollPhysics(),
      children: [
        SingleComponent('Fotorresistor', 'assets/images/fotor1.png',
            'assets/images/fotor2.png', 'assets/images/fotor3.png', '', ''),
        SingleComponent('Potenciómetro', '', '', '', '', ''),
        Testing(Colors.blue),
        Testing(Colors.green),
      ],
    );
  }
}

class Testing extends StatelessWidget {
  final Color color;
  const Testing(this.color);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      color: this.color,
    );
  }
}



class SingleComponent extends StatefulWidget {
  final String name;
  final String image1;
  final String image2;
  final String image3;
  final String description;
  final String utilities;
  
  int current_section = 0;
  Color info_color = Color(0xffBDE3BE);
  Color videos_color = Color(0xffBDE3BE);
  Color preguntas_color = Color(0xffBDE3BE);

  SingleComponent(this.name, this.image1, this.image2, this.image3,
      this.description, this.utilities);

  @override
  _SingleComponentState createState() => _SingleComponentState();
}

class _SingleComponentState extends State<SingleComponent> {

  _optionSelected(int index) {
    setState(() {
      widget.current_section = index;
      widget.videos_color = Color(0xffBDE3BE);
      widget.preguntas_color = Color(0xffBDE3BE);
      widget.info_color = Color(0xffBDE3BE);
      if (index == 0) {
        debugPrint("Hola");
        // info_color = Color(0xff4AB14E);
        widget.info_color = Colors.white;
      }
      else if (index == 1) {
        debugPrint("Hola2");
        widget.videos_color = Color(0xff4AB14E);
      }else if (index == 2) {
        debugPrint("Hola3");
        widget.preguntas_color = Color(0xff4AB14E);
      }
    });

  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return 
      Scaffold(
      //backgroundColor: Color(0xff333333),
      body: Column(
        children: [
          Container(
            child: Text(
              widget.name,
              style: TextStyle(
                  color: Color(0xff4AB14E),
                  fontSize: 26,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
            ),
            alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
            margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 50),
          ),
          CardImageList(widget.image1, widget.image2, widget.image3),
          Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left:28.0),
      child: Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
        children: [
          FlatButton(onPressed: _optionSelected(0), child: Text('Información', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 17, color: widget.info_color),)),
          FlatButton(onPressed: _optionSelected(1), child: Text('Videos', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 17, color: widget.videos_color),)),
          FlatButton(onPressed: _optionSelected(2), child: Text('Preguntas', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 17, color: widget.preguntas_color),)),
        ],
      ),
    ),


        ],
      ),
    );
    
  }
}
```

If someone can help me with this it would be awesome, thanks :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling `_optionSelected()` method in wrong way.

Instead of this: `onPressed: _optionSelected(0)`

Call like this: `onPressed: () => _optionSelected(0)`